# How to clear uncontrolled field in react

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I used to use ref for forms but now I always state for forms, I'm facing an issue where I have to clear a field after user submitted something.

```
handleSumbit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const todoText = this.state.todoText
        if(todoText.length > 0){
            this.refs.todoTextElem = "" // wont work
            this.props.onAddTodo(todoText)
        } else {
            this.refs.todoTextElem.focus() //worked
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSumbit}>
                    <input ref="todoTextElem" type="text" onChange={e => this.setState({todoText: e.target.value})} name="todoText" placeholder="What do you need to do?" />
                    <button className="button expanded">Add Todo</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Clearing the ref simply don't work because it's a controlled input. I don't want to do something stupid like

passing a flag from parent component telling the form is submitted then use setState to clear the input. Or make onAddTodo to have a callback so that I can do

```
this.props.onAddTodo(todoText).then(()=>this.state({todoText:""}))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you are using the input element is [uncontrolled](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/uncontrolled-components.html), because you are not using the value property, means not controlling it's value. Simply storing the value in state variable.

---

You don't need to store the input field value in state variable if you are using [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) will have the reference of `DOM element`, so you need to use `this.refName.value` to access the value of that element.

**Steps:**

**1-** Write the input element like this:

```
<input 
    ref= {el => this.todoTextElem = el} 
    type="text" 
    placeholder="What do you need to do?" />
```

To get it's value: `this.todoTextElem.value`

**2-** To **clear the uncontrolled input field**, clear it's value using [ref](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html):

```
this.todoTextElem.value = '';
```

Write it like this:

```
handleSumbit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const todoText = this.todoTextElem.value;
    if(todoText.length > 0){

        this.todoTextElem.value = '';     //here

        this.props.onAddTodo(todoText)
    } else {
        this.todoTextElem.focus() 
    }
}
```

Another change is about the **[string refs, As per DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#legacy-api-string-refs)**:

> If you worked with React before, you might be familiar with an older
>   API where the ref attribute is a string, like "textInput", and the DOM
>   node is accessed as this.refs.textInput. We advise against it because
>   string refs have some issues, are considered legacy, and are likely to
>   be removed in one of the future releases. If you're currently using
>   this.refs.textInput to access refs, we recommend the callback pattern
>   instead.

Comment: is it good to use ref instead of state for form if the form has stuff like checkbox and radio button?

Comment: generally we should try to avoid the use of ref, always use state variable. check this what doc says about ref: [When to Use Refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs) and  [Don't Overuse Refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs)

Comment: but you used ref in your form above? lol.If you use state, means 1 more rerender if u want to clear the input's field to empty. Is that fine or I'm over worried bout performance?

Comment: reason why i used ref is, you want to focus the field for that ref is required, check the link [**When to Use refs --> Managing focus**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs)

Answer (score 0):

Try and use functional refs instead. Note that the ref is to a DOM element, meaning you still need to address its properties (`.value`) to modify them as opposed to trying to overwriting the element directly.
The following should work:

```
handleSumbit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const todoText = this.state.todoText
    if(todoText.length > 0){
        this.todoTextElem.value = ""
        this.props.onAddTodo(todoText)
    } else {
        this.todoTextElem.focus()
    }
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.handleSumbit}>
                <input ref={input => this.todoTextElem = input} type="text" onChange={e => this.setState({todoText: e.target.value})} name="todoText" placeholder="What do you need to do?" />
                <button className="button expanded">Add Todo</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```